# Как передать массив в виде аргумента в OpenCL

Tags: java, opencl

Вопрос: как можно в `jocl` предать массив в виде аргумента?

Answer (score 2):

Да по-простому передать, например, 3 разных массива (только одномерные можно!!):
   **kernel void MyKernel(
      global const int* IntParams,
      global float* DeltaH,
      global float2* Qxy,

  ...**
На хосте надо :
а) Выделить память под каждый массив (в байтах) - **clCreateBuffer**
б) Пронумеровать аргументы-массивы Kernel - **clSetKernelArg**
в) Записать массив из памяти CPU в выделенную память GPU - **clEnqueueWriteBuffer**
г) При необходимости прочитать массив с результатами расчётов обратно - **clEnqueueReadBuffer**